# Convex Analysis

Tags: analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $Y$ is vector topo space, $A\neq \emptyset, A \subset Y$ and $K$ is convex cone. Then

$$cl(A+K)+K=cl(A+K).$$

I need show that.

I have proof as follows:

For any $z \in cl(A+K)+K,$ exist ${a_{n}} \subset A,{b_{n}} \subset K, b' \in K$ such that $a_{n}+ b_{n}+ b' \to z$. Suppose that $b'_{n}:=b_{n}+b'$. Since $K + K \subset K$ so ${b'_{n}} \subset K$.
Therefore, $z \in cl(A+K)$.

Is that true?
Thanks for help me.

Comment: One problem you need to fix is your assumption that for any limit point of the set, there is necessarily a sequence in the set which converges to that limit point. That works in metric spaces, but it need not be true for general topological vector spaces. You can either replace "sequence" with something more general, or (better) figure out how to say this without using sequences.

Comment: A second thing may or may not be an issue. Has it been proven in your course that if $K$ is convex cone, then $K + K \subseteq K$? If not, then you should demonstrate that in your proof. If it has, your proof is fine once you fix the sequence issue.